# using EXPLAIN for MYSQL stored procedure calls

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do analyse and use EXPLAIN for my stored procedure calls ? 
I need to optimize the query time, however seems like there is no where i can do a EXPLAIN call proc_name() ?

Answer (score 30):

You can try

```
set profiling=1;
call proc_name();
show profiles;
```

Comment: That does not reveal the execution plan, but it does show how long each query in the procedure took.

Answer (score 11):

at present you can't explain stored procedures in mysql - but you could do something like this:

```
drop procedure if exists get_user;
delimiter #
create procedure get_user
(
in p_user_id int unsigned,
in p_explain tinyint unsigned
)
begin
  if (p_explain) then
    explain select * from users where user_id = p_user_id;
  end if;
  select * from users where user_id = p_user_id;
end#

delimiter ;

call get_user(1,1);
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It does explains the querry inside the procedure if you call it

Answer (score 3):

**Prior to MySQL 5.7**:

`EXPLAIN` worked only on `SELECT` statements, except when you use `EXPLAIN` tablename which is an alias of `DESCRIBE tablename`

**after 5.7:**

`EXPLAIN` works with `SELECT DELETE INSERT REPLACE UPDATE` statements

Comment: `EXPLAIN` works with `SELECT DELETE INSERT REPLACE UPDATE` statements, as stated in [MySQL 5.7 doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Comment: @Xenos did you... see the date of my answer?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's worth a mention, so others readers are up-to-date and not sticking to old obsolete answers

Comment: @Xenos in a case like this, it's better to edit the answer, as long as it's in line with the original answer, and is no longer a dupe.  If it's a dupe-after-edit you can flag to remove to avoid confusion. If you didn't have the rep at the time to edit, then agree that commenting is a good way to help others until the edit is approved.