# postgreSQL explain analyse a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to understand the query optimization in postgresql and I have a function with some queries in it. Some of them are simple querys that saves a value into a variable and then the next query takes this variable to find something.. lets say:

```
 function()...
select type into t
from tableA
where code = a_c;

select num into n
from tableB
where id = t; 
end function...
```

and many more.. If I want to explain analyse the whole function I execute the command explain analyse select function(); Is this the right way to do it or should I have to explain analyse every query inside the function and if so with what values?

Comment: If you do "explain analyse" for every individual query, you will be able to see if a particular query can be optimized. Not sure how it works on the level of function, and whether it makes sense.

Comment: You can put the function body into a `PREPARE thing (arg1, arg2, ...) AS ... original body ...; ` and call that using `explain analyze execute thing (args);`

Comment: @wildplasser there is an error with the declare statements inside the body and if I dont declare them I get this error: utility statements cannot be prepared

Comment: Note: there are no "declare statements" in the question. (and there is no declare statement in SQL)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the [auto_explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module:

> The auto_explain module provides a means for logging execution plans
>   of slow statements automatically, without having to run EXPLAIN by
>   hand. This is especially helpful for tracking down un-optimized
>   queries in large applications.

with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements` turned on:

> **auto_explain.log_nested_statements** (boolean)
>
> auto_explain.log_nested_statements causes nested statements
>    (**statements executed inside a function**) to be considered for logging.
>   When it is off, only top-level query plans are logged. This parameter
>   is off by default. Only superusers can change this setting.

Comment: I tried to do this but the output  I got is what the function returns.                                                                                               the code I used is: LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on;
select find_4();

Comment: The results of `explain` done by this module go into the server's log, it does not change the output you get.

Answer (score 0):

*( [pulling from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390086/263858) )*

You can explain stored procedures through the use of this pattern for stored procedures.

```
drop procedure if exists get_user;
delimiter #
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user
(
in p_user_id int unsigned,
in p_explain tinyint unsigned
)
begin
  if (p_explain) then
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
      select * from users where user_id = p_user_id;
  end if;

  select * from users where user_id = p_user_id;
end#

delimiter ;

call get_user(1,1);
```

this is obviously an inconvenient solution, if the stored procedure wraps a very complicated query